# Is there any command similar to Delaunay of matlab?

Tags: functions, programming, computational-geometry

After finding this [webpage](https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39559-automatic-terrain-generation) where they mention the generation of land using matlab,

[image]

In its section how it works, explain its operation in detail,

[image: interes]

I started trying to do it in MMA but I am doubtful of the Delaunay command that has matlab because I have not found its equivalent in MMA, then I show you the little progress I have, maybe someone has the answer to my question, thanks in advance.

The same in wolfram mathetica, I believe

```
x=0.25*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],3];
y=0.25*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],3];
h=0.1*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],3];
```

Here is the command that I have not found in mathematica, because numbers are not obtained, such as those obtained in the follow image

[image: capture2]

Any help is welcome,

Comment: `DelaunayMesh`? There are also several other Delaunay-related functions if you search the documentation for "Delaunay", some of which appear quite specialised. I have a hard time understanding exactly what you want this function to do, and do not have a copy of MatLab to see their documentation either. Perhaps you can try to add a little more detail and clarity to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the following works.  I'll create some points

```
pts = Table[(5 + t) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5}] // N
(* {{5., 0.}, {3.24181, 5.04883}, {-2.91303, 6.36508}, {-7.91994,
   1.12896}, {-5.88279, -6.81122}, {2.83662, -9.58924}} *)
```

and extract the cells of the triangulation

```
MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[pts], 2]
(* {Polygon[{3, 4, 1}], Polygon[{1, 4, 5}], Polygon[{1, 2, 3}], 
 Polygon[{1, 5, 6}]} *)
```

For comparison in **Octave** (similar to MATLAB)

```
 >> pts = [[5., 0.]; [3.24181, 5.04883]; [-2.91303, 6.36508]; [-7.91994, 1.12896];[-5.88279, -6.81122]; [2.83662, -9.58924]];

>> delaunay(pts)
ans =

3   1   4
5   1   4
5   6   1
2   3   1
```

So the same triangles, but in a different order.

Comment: With that detailed explanation it has become clear to me the use of the commands you showed, in addition to obtaining the same triangles, thanks for dedicating your time to this question and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Using `pts` from mikado's answer:

```
DelaunayMesh[pts]["Faces"]
```

> {{3, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 6}}

```
Grid @ %
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing a shorter way of obtaining the triangles that mikado obtained, it is very useful for me. I would like to ask you if it would be a good idea to create a new thread so that we could do what is mentioned on the page I shared but using mathematica,  thanks in advance